# Attribute name affecting validation operation? (MVC/Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, validation

I have a form that uses the standard MVC 3.0 template validation (jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js).  I have a model that consists of a single string attribute with a [Required] attribute as follows:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Testing { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a respective view Test.cshtml with a form showing the field and validation message

```
@model RealEstate.ViewModels.TestViewModel 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Testing)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Testing)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Testing)
        </div>

        <p>
            <button type="submit" name="buttonValue" value="Ok">Ok</button>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

In the controller I am invoking the view as follows:

```
return View("Test");
```

The problem is that in certain forms I was noting that the validation message was showing as soon as the form loads (not after postback as one would expect).  In other forms, the same setup was functioning properly.  Through further investigation of this problem I weirdly discovered that the behaviour was determined by the attribute name.  For instance, if I name the attribute "Description" (in both model and view) validation does not work properly whilst if I name the attribute "Testing" (as in the example) everything works fine.  Has anyone encountered the same problem?